# Wrap method & event handler in a single method call

Tags: c#, .net

This might be a really stupid question, especially coming from someone who has worked in .Net for a few years. The question is simple:

> Is there a way to wrap a method call + the an event handler, created
>   from that method in a single method call

Based on my understanding, it is not. Here's an example:

```
// Starts the long running transaction, when this method completes
// we have no idea whether the transaction actually succeeded/failed
// /finished/etc
public bool BeginLongRunningTransaction(/*args*/)
{
    myService.LongRunningTransactionComplete += TransactionComplete;

    // Runs the actual transaction - this can take some time
    myService.ExecuteLongRunningTransaction();
    return true;
}

// Handles the long running transaction complete event
// which allows us to see if the transaction suceeded/failed/etc
private void TransactionComplete(/*args*/)
{
    /* Stuff complete! */
}
```

What will happen, is that a *caller* will call BeginLongRunningTransaction() method, which will begin the long running transaction but will not be able to return a result of that transaction, as that result will come back in TransactionComplete() event handler. What I am trying to see is whether there is a way to both Begin and return the result of the long running transaction inside the BeginLongRunningTransaction() method, so to the *caller*,

I am aware of sync-await pattern and also know about inline event handlers. In my understanding, neither of those are able to achieve what I am trying to.

The main reason for this question is simplifying the communication from the subscribing client's point of view.

Many thanks!

Comment: What is myService? Is it a webservice? What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: _"the request to DoStuff() and the actual DoStuff() functionality will be done on separate threads"_ -- says who? There's nothing at all in your question that suggests multiple threads are involved at all. It's certainly not implicit when using `event` in C#, nor of method calls generally. Your question is way too vague and unclear. Fix your question so it includes a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, and explain _precisely_ what it is that code does and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: Apologies for not being more clear. I tried to keep the example as simple as possible. I have updated the question with better naming + comments to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
public bool DoStuff(/*args*/)
{
    myService.StuffComplete += (/*args*/) => { /* Stuff complete! */ };
    myService.DoStuff();
    return true;
}
```

But, if you mean that you want the the return value from `public bool DoStuff(/*args*/)` to be the result of something that happens in `/* Stuff complete! */` rather than a hard-coded `true` then you need to be a bit more clever.

You could do something like this:

```
public bool DoStuff(/*args*/)
{
    bool result = false;
    myService.StuffComplete += (/*args*/) =>
    {
        result = myService.Status;
    };
    myService.DoStuff();
    return result;
}
```

Here this code expects that the call runs purely on the current thread. If `myService.DoStuff()` launches a new thread then the `myService.StuffComplete` handler will run after `public bool DoStuff(/*args*/)` has completed and you won't get the result you expect.

If you think that `myService` does invoke new threads behind the scenes (or you wish to have the code run on a background task) then you should look at using Microsoft's Reactive Framework. Then you can do this:

```
public IObservable<bool> DoStuff(/*args*/)
{
    return Observable.Create<bool>(o =>
    {
        var subscription =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(
                    h => myService.StuffComplete += h,
                    h => myService.StuffComplete -= h)
                .Select(x => myService.Status)
                .Take(1)
                .Subscribe(o);
        myService.DoStuff();
        return subscription;
    });
}
```

This changes the output of the method from `bool` to `IObservable<bool>`, which means that you can observe the result when it is ready.

```
DoStuff().Subscribe(result => { /* handle result */ };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for an excellent answer! I feel quite stupid now for not having figured that out myself, especially that I did look into the inline event handlers before. I think the part where I got confused is threading - I assumed that the long running transaction (DoStuff()) will be performed on a different thread, which it does not have to. I also had no idea about the Reactive framework, but that does look very useful for when DoStuff() does happen on a different thread.

Answer (score -1):

Try use async-await.

little code example (I was not test):

```
class YourClass
{
    public async Task<bool> DoStuff(/*args*/)
    {
        var handler = new StuffCompleteHandler(myService);
        await handler.GetTask();
        return true;
    }

    private class StuffCompleteHandler
    {
        private ???? myService;
        private TaskCompletionSource<bool> taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        public StuffCompleteHandler(???? myService)
        {
            this.myService = myService;
            this.myService.StuffComplete += this.StuffComplete;
        }

        private void StuffComplete(/*args*/)
        {
            this.myService.StuffComplete -= this.StuffComplete;
            try
            {
                /* Stuff complete! */
                // do some thing
                this.taskSource.SetResult(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                this.taskSource.SetException(e);
            }
        }

        public Task GetTask() => this.taskSource.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I think this does not get me quite the result I was hoping for, but it is still an interesting pattern to consider.